# How to send a bitmap and text data thought processes using file mapping?

Tags: winapi, ipc, autohotkey, file-mapping

Im trying to send a `bitmap` and some `text` string from a script to another using `file mapping`, below is my attempt:

```
FM := new FileMapping()
Return

F1:: FM.Read()
Esc::ExitApp

F2:: ; Write the pbitmap to map

; GDIp startup
VarSetCapacity(si, 8 + A_PtrSize*2, 0), si := Chr(1)
DllCall("gdiplus\GdiplusStartup", "UPtrP", pToken, "Ptr", &si, "Ptr", 0)
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------

; Create the pBitmap #1
File := "test.png"
DllCall("gdiplus\GdipCreateBitmapFromFile", "WStr", File, "PtrP", pBitmap)
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------

; LockBits #2
DllCall("gdiplus\GdipGetImageDimension", Ptr, pBitmap, "float*", width, "float*", height)
DllCall("gdiplus\GdipGetImagePixelFormat", "Ptr", pBitmap, "PtrP", pixelFormat)

VarSetCapacity(Rect, 16)
NumPut(0, Rect, 0, "UInt")
NumPut(0, Rect, 4, "UInt")
NumPut(width, Rect, 8, "UInt")
NumPut(height, Rect, 12, "UInt")

VarSetCapacity(BitmapData, 16+2*(A_PtrSize ? A_PtrSize : 4), 0)
E := DllCall("Gdiplus\GdipBitmapLockBits", "Ptr", pBitmap, "Ptr", &Rect, "UInt", LockMode:=3, "Int", PixelFormat, "Ptr", &BitmapData)
Stride := NumGet(BitmapData, 8, "Int")
Scan0  := NumGet(BitmapData, 16)
size := stride * height
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------


; Append a string into the data 
; that will be saved on memory #3
str  := "test test"
      
VarSetCapacity(data, dataSize := size + 16 + StrLen(str)*2 + 2, 0)
StrPut(str, &data + size + 16)

; Copty the data to memory #4
DllCall("RtlCopyMemory", "Ptr", &data + 16, "Ptr", scan0, "Ptr", size)

DllCall("Gdiplus\GdipBitmapUnlockBits", "UPtr", pBitmap, "UPtr", &BitmapData) 

; ------------------------------------------------------------------------


; Write to map #5
NumPut(pixelFormat, data)
NumPut(width      , data, 4)
NumPut(height     , data, 8)
NumPut(stride     , data, 12, "UInt")

VarSetCapacity(COPYDATASTRUCT, A_PtrSize*3, 0)
NumPut(dataSize, COPYDATASTRUCT, A_PtrSize)
NumPut(&data, COPYDATASTRUCT, A_PtrSize*2)

FM.Write(&COPYDATASTRUCT)
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Return



Class FileMapping {
   
   __New(Name="Global\MyFileMappingObject", BufSize=100000) {    
      
      ; Opens existing or creates new file mapping object
      static INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE := -1, PAGE_READWRITE := 0x4, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS := 0xF001F
      
      hMapFile := DllCall("OpenFileMapping", "Ptr", FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, "Int", 0, "Str", Name)
      
      if ( hMapFile == 0 ) {        
         ; OpenFileMapping Failed - file mapping object doesn't exist - that means we have to create it
         hMapFile := DllCall("CreateFileMapping", "Ptr", INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, "Ptr", 0, "Int", PAGE_READWRITE, "Int", 0, "Int", BufSize, "Str", Name)
         if ( hMapFile == 0 )    ; CreateFileMapping Failed
               return
      }

      pBuf := DllCall("MapViewOfFile", "Ptr", hMapFile, "Int", FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, "Int", 0, "Int", 0, "Ptr", BufSize)
      
      if ( pBuf == 0 ) ; MapViewOfFile Failed
         return

      this.Name     := Name
      this.hMapFile := hMapFile
      this.pBuf     := pBuf
      this.BufSize  := BufSize
      
   }
   


   Write(data:="") {       
      NumPut(data, this.pBuf)
   }



   Read() {

      static flags := HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY := 0x00000008
         , hHeap := DllCall("GetProcessHeap", "Ptr")

      param := NumGet(this.pBuf)
      size  := NumGet(param + A_PtrSize, "UInt")
      pData := NumGet(param + A_PtrSize*2)

      pHeap := DllCall("HeapAlloc", "Ptr", hHeap, "UInt", flags, "UPtr", size, "Ptr")
      DllCall("RtlCopyMemory", "Ptr", pHeap, "Ptr", pData, "Ptr", size)

      this.CreateBitmapFromData(hHeap, pHeap)
      return

   }



   CreateBitmapFromData(hHeap, pImageData) {

      pixelFormat := NumGet(pImageData+0, "UInt")
      width       := NumGet(pImageData+4, "UInt")
      height      := NumGet(pImageData+8, "UInt")
      stride      := NumGet(pImageData+12,"UInt")
      ; The string appended in the step #3 ("test test")
      str         := StrGet(pImageData + 16 + stride*height)


      
      DllCall("gdiplus\GdipCreateBitmapFromScan0", "Int", width, "Int", height, "Int", stride, "Int", pixelFormat, "Ptr", pImageData + 16, "PtrP", pBitmap)

      DllCall("gdiplus\GdipCreateHBITMAPFromBitmap", "Ptr", pBitmap, "PtrP", hbm, "Int", 0xffffffff)

      ; Just for test, create a gui showing the picture.
      Gui, Add, Picture, x0 y0, % "HBITMAP:" hbm
      Gui, Show

      DllCall("HeapFree", "Ptr", hHeap, "UInt", 0, "Ptr", pImageData)
      DllCall("gdiplus\GdipDisposeImage", "Ptr", pBitmap)

   }



   __Delete() {
      DllCall("UnmapViewOfFile", "Ptr", this.pBuf), DllCall("CloseHandle", "Ptr", this.hMapFile)
   }

}
```

To write the bitmap and text to the filemap you hit `F2`

it will create a bitmap(#1) from the given file

call lockbits(#2) on the bitmap, save the scan and a string (#3) into `data` and copy the `data` to memory (#4) utilizing `RtlCopyMemory`

then, save `data` into the filemap (#5)

When you hit `F1` it will call the function `Read()` from the `Class FileMap`
and will 'rebuild' the bitmap (`CreateBitmapFromData`) that has been save inside of the filemap, and also read the string appended in step #3

Things works as described as long its read/written from the same script, if i launch a different process and call `FM.Read()` it doesnt work, the values of `size` and `pData` inside of the function `Read()` are blank:

```
  param := NumGet(this.pBuf)
  size  := NumGet(param + A_PtrSize, "UInt")
  pData := NumGet(param + A_PtrSize*2)
```

Appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 1):

You have to add some more error handling. Check all return values and call

```
DllCall("GetLastError")
```

after functions which do not return error codes. That will tell much about what's going on. Without that, it would be difficult to give a complete answer as there are many things that can go wrong.

Use one of the AutoHotkey debugger extensions for VS Code like this one:
[AutoHotkey Plus](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cweijan.vscode-autohotkey-plus)